# How can retrofit 2.3 can parse nested jsonObject and multiple Array with keys and values

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

As Couple day R&D, I found some solution can do this thing, However I can not show any response from JSON API with retrofit 2.3 version. I know this question could be duplicated, However, Could anybody help me. This is how JSON API look like

```
{
 "GetInsertPageInfoResponse": {
  "Request": {
   "IsValid": "True",
   "GetInsertPageInfoRequest": null
   },
  "GetInsertPageInfo": {
   "1": [
    {
     "cat_name": "test1",
     "image_thumb_path": "insertPage/thumb/taputapu",
     "image_original_path": "upload/insertPage/original/book",
     "cat_icon_path": "upload/insertPage/cat_icon/icon.png",
     "cat_version": "8",
     "item_id": "1",
     "item_name": "01.jpg"
    }
   ],
   2: [
    {
     "cat_name": "test2",
     "image_thumb_path": "upload/insertPage/thumb/taputapu",
     "image_original_path": "photobook/upload/insertPage/original/book",
     "cat_icon_path": "upload/insertPage/cat_icon/icon.png",
     "cat_version": "6",
     "item_id": "3",
     "item_name": "08.jpg"
    }
   ]
 }
}}
```

This is what I tried to parse json, but it's still not working

```
public class APIClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

This is how I get the service

```
    public interface APIService {
    @GET("?Service=Core&Operation=GetInsertPageInfo")
    Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> getInsertPageInfoCall();
   }

public class APIUtils {
    public static APIService getSOService() {
        return APIClient.getClient(API_ROOT_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

I tried to use this POJOs

```
public class GetInsertPageInfoResponse {
    @SerializedName("GetInsertPageInfoResponse")
    @Expose
    private GetInsertPageInfo getInsertPageInfo;
}

public class GetInsertPageInfo {
    @SerializedName("GetInsertPageInfo")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, List<AsobieItem>> mPageInfo;

    public Map<String, List<AsobieItem>> getmPageInfo() {
        return mPageInfo;
    }

    public void setmPageInfo(Map<String, List<AsobieItem>> mPageInfo) {
        this.mPageInfo = mPageInfo;
    }
}

public class AsobieItem {
    @SerializedName("cat_name")
    @Expose
    private String cateName;
    @SerializedName("image_thumb_path")
    @Expose
    private String imageThumbPath;
    @SerializedName("image_original_path")
    @Expose
    private String imageOriginalPath;
    @SerializedName("cat_icon_path")
    @Expose
    private String catIconPath;
    @SerializedName("cat_version")
    @Expose
    private String catVersion;
    @SerializedName("item_id")
    @Expose
    private String itemId;
    @SerializedName("item_name")
    @Expose
    private String itemName;
}
```

**UPDATE!!**
This is how I request by using retrofit 2 in Activity class:

```
APIService mApiService = APIUtils.getSOService();

public void callAPIGetInsertPageInfo() {
        mApiService.getInsertPageInfoCall().enqueue(new Callback<GetInsertPageInfoResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> call, Response<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i("Response", response.body().toString());
                    Log.d("GetResponse",  response.raw().toString());


                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    // handle request errors depending on status code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                //TODO 
            }
        });
    }
```

When I Logged the Response, I see this error: `Response ID 525295 is not served in this process.`

Comment: @GET("?Service=Core&Operation=GetInsertPageInfo")
Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> getInsertPageInfoCall();
this is not correct way to implement interface in retrofit, my friend

Comment: @PhanDinhThai I updated my question. How could I fix it?

Comment: show me your base_url and you should remove @Expose if you do not use it

Comment: @PhanDinhThai I'm sorry, but I cannot show my base_url for some customer Information security reasons. However, my JSON API format exactly the same as I posted one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple day I found out by myself. I use the `HashMap<>` and `List<List<Item>>` to match with that kind of JSON API.
I declare a POJO with a `List<Item>` and a `id` to identify them

```
public class ListWithId {
    private List<Item> items;
    private int id;

    public ListWithId(List<Item> items, int id){
        this.items = items;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

In the `Activity.class` I use this `Object` to strore all data into

```
 private List<ListWithId> listTC;


public void callAPIGetInsertPageInfo() {
        mApiService.getInsertPageInfoCall(Constants.CORE_PARAM, Constants.GET_RESPONSE_PARAM).enqueue(new Callback<GetInsertPageInfoResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> call, Response<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<AsobieItem>> entry : response.body().getGetInsertPageInfo().getmPageInfo().entrySet()) {
                        listTC.add(new ListWithId(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()));
                    }

                    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(Activity.this, listTC);
                    refreshAdapter();
                    // set adapter for list view

                    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                } else {
                    int statusCode = response.code();
                    // handle request errors depending on status code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                //TODO FAIL
            }
        });
    }
```

When I get Logged to get the keys and values. It'll like this

```
Keys: 1
Values: "1":[{ListItem}, {ListItem}]
Keys: 2
Values: "2":[{ListItem2}, {ListItem2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`HashMap<Integer,List<MyObject> GetInsertPageInfo`

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all I think you should change you base url.
   Ex: if you `base_url` now is `abc.com/help/dosth` --> you should change you `base_url` to `abc.com/`
2. Them re-implement you `API interface` as

   ```
   public interface APIService {
       @GET("help/dosth")
       Call<GetInsertPageInfoResponse> getInsertPageInfoCall(@Query("Service") String service, @Query("Operation") String operation);
   }
   ```
3. Then call API with params and see what happen. In you code I saw POJO objects still not correct totally but let's see it later

Comment: I got this Log, That's URL is correct, but I still can not show entire my json format to String.
`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://example.com/api/json.php/?Service=Core&Operation=GetInsertPageInfo}`

Comment: what do you mean in show entire json format to String?